# Angular Xeditable - can't get correct value for validation using onbeforesave event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-xeditable

I am trying to add validation logic to the editing of message format values we use. I have created plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/nBnoJLdqE5ger1OmbmbD?p=preview) to show the issue. Here is the code for the curly brace validation.

```
vm.formatCheck = function (resource) {

console.log(resource.Value);

if (resource.Value.indexOf('{') > -1 || resource.Value.indexOf('}') > -1) {

    var x = resource.Value.split('{').length - 1;
    var y = resource.Value.split('}').length - 1;

    if ((x + y) % 2 === 1) {
        alert("Incorrect Message format");
        return;
    }

  }
};
```

Example: If you edit the first value (`{JobRole} for {Organisation}`) and remove the trailing curly brace (`{JobRole} for {Organisation`)

The `alert("Incorrect Message format");` never shows because it gets the original value - `{JobRole} for {Organisation}` and not `{JobRole} for {Organisation`

If I move the validation logic to the `onaftersave` event I get the correct value and validation fires, but it will show/save the incorrect value, which I **do not** want. So how can I get around this? Any help appreciated.

- Not sure if I could use defer, promise to resolve this - but not sure if even possible with Angular Xeditable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my plunker with it working: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8O874L4Wu2oNRkm7DvUU?p=preview)

Basically, I changed your html to this:

```
<a href="#" e-name="resource" editable-textarea="res.Value" e-rows="5" e-cols="30"
                   onbeforesave="vm.formatCheck($data)"
                   onaftersave="vm.onGridItemChanged(res)">{{ res.Value || 'empty' }}</a></a>
```

I'm passing $data instead of the 'res'. $data is the value of the object property you are actually changing.

And in the controller, your validation function. 'Resource' is now the $data which contains the value of your property you are trying to change. So you check it, and you return an error message. If you don't want a error message to show up next to the field return "";

```
vm.formatCheck = function (resource) {

        console.log(resource);

        if (resource.indexOf('{') > -1 || resource.indexOf('}') > -1) {

            var x = resource.split('{').length - 1;
            var y = resource.split('}').length - 1;

            if ((x + y) % 2 === 1) {
                alert("Incorrect Message format");
                return "Incorrect Message format";
            }

        }
    };
```